# How to install moinmoin-2 on dreamhost

Tags: python, phusion-passenger, wsgi, dreamhost, moinmoin

How to install moinmoin-2 on dreamhost?

I'm putting this here, so I can find it in the future.  Maybe it is useful to other people too.

I found it challenging because:

- it needs python2.7, and dreamhost has 2.4, 2.5, 2.6
- it needs Flask, which I've never used before
- it needs virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install python2.7, from parts 1 to 3 of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953695/update-django-1-4-and-python-2-7-3-with-virtualenv-on-dreamhost-with-passenger
2. Download moin-2.0, eg from hg:

   hg clone http://hg.moinmo.in/moin/2.0 moin-2.0
3. `cd moin-2.0`
4. edit the quickinstall to comment out the line `$VIRTUALENV --no-site-packages --python $PYTHON $DIR || exit 1`

   - this is so that you can create your own `env` directory
5. `rm -R` the old moin-2.0/env directory
6. Use virtualenv to create the env directory, making sure to add the option `--no-site-packages`
7. Run `./quickinstall`
8. Follow the moin instructions to build indexes and so on
9. In your dreamhost control panel, create a new subdomain, with 'passenger' activated, and some path ending in `/public`, but not the moin-2.0 directory itself.  Let's call this path `$SITE/public`, so `$SITE` is the parent director of the `public` directory
10. In `$SITE`, create the following file called `passenger_wsgi.py`:

    ```
    import sys, os
    INTERP = '/path/to/moin-2.0/env/bin/python'
    if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
    from MoinMoin.app import create_app
    application = create_app('/path/to/moin2.0/wikiconfig.py')
    ```

    (you need to replace `/path/to/moin2.0` with the directory of your `moin-2.0` directory)
11. Create a file $SITE/tmp/restart.txt (or `touch` it if it already exists)